# unable to deploy nextjs app on AWS lightsail server from .next folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, yarn-v2

I created web app using nextjs. I am using Yarn. I want to deploy app on the AWS lightsail server, I get bitnami nodejs server. When I run the yarn build command, under the .next folder package.json contain only following line `{"type": "commonjs"}`
Do I need to copy the dependencies from the source folder package.json?

```
{
  "name": "XXXX",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.3",
    "next": "13.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-player": "^2.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

I want to deploy files from .next folder. Please guide me how to deploy code from .next folder. My understanding is that I do not need to clone/ftp complete project. I only need to upload files from .next folder. Can anyone guide me how to deploy my nextjs app?